# Saving objects to a Data Structure or a File in JAVA

Tags: java, oop, security, arraylist

**Langauge**

Java

**Application:**

Patient Viewer/Creator

**Question**

1. How should I handle the objects being created?
2. What are the negatives of saving Patient objects to a structure as they are being created? Any positives?

**Current Implementation:**

My initial thought was to create an ArrayList or Map and save Patient objects to the data structure as they are being created. Doing a little bit of research I found that doing something like this might not be the most secure thing to do, with things like memory leakage.(What are the other negatives?)

```
public class PatientApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<>();
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    patientList.add(patient);
  }
}
```

Then I figured I could saved the patient objects to a file and load that file when I need to retrieve patient information. Would that be a better implementation?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. May be you want to read about storing in DB or serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement Java `Serializable` interface by the `Patient` class, also be careful that the `Patient` class does not contain any non-serializable property (try to keep limited within primitive types of properties). Then you will be able to save the objects of class `Patient` to a file easily (also can transfer through network!).

Actually you should keep patient information in a storage (e.g. database). Moreover keep in mind that you cannot work on an object saved in secondary storage unless you recreate or restore their saved states in the main memory (i.e. in the RAM). So, if you want to do some operations on a number of patients simultaneously(!) you should keep them in a List like data structure (not in a file).

To learn more search for `Java Object Serialization`.

Comment: Thank you. To make sure I'm getting this right(& hammer this into my head) you're saying when the Patient object is created and the properties are set, I should save it to the DB. If I want to do work on it I have to load the Patient from the database onto a data structure?

Comment: To do operation on the data (i.e. instances of `Patient`) you must keep them in a data structure (in the RAM, but leak of memory is your concern, you have to program in such a way that ensures no memory leaking; system bug may be an exception). But if you need to save them for further use (e.g. after a restart) you must use permanent storage like file or database.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what's your requirement. What is the scope of the patient object? Arraylist and other data structures are not permanent storage so we cannot compare these data structures and permanent storage such as file or database.